# How do computational chemistry programs determine the irreducible representation of a molecular orbital?

Tags: computational-chemistry, orbitals, symmetry

I was coding a simple RHF code to test my understanding of computational chemistry when I stumbled upon this question. How exactly do computer programs like Gaussian, GAMESS-US etc. know which irreducible representation to assign to the molecular orbitals generated?

Comment: A molecule has a point group; a molecular orbital (or a group of MOs) has an irreducible representation.

Comment: The software constructs a symmetry adapted linear combinations (SALC) of the AOs. The IRREPs of the MOs follow directly from that: each MO is formed from SALCs of the same IRREP only.

Comment: Thanks. How exactly does the software construct these SALCs? Projection Operator/Schmidt orthonormalisation?